# How to compare different lengths of a vector?

Tags: r, vector, compare

I have two vectors:

```
A <- 10 10 20 19 24 24 17 18 24 24 24 25 16 16 16 25 25 12 12 12 25 24 24 24 24  2  2
```

and

```
B <- 2 4 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 3 2
```

I would like to compare the first two elements of A (here:`10 10`). Why? Because B's first entry is two. Then I would like to compare the elements 3 to 6 from A (that is: `20 19 24 24`) because B's second element is 4. And so on...

When I say I want to compare them, what I want to do is to see if any element of the chosen range is below a threshold (e.g. below 20) and another element of them larger than another threshold (e.g. 23).

The desired output would be to count how many times this two conditions where
fulfilled (here at max 11 times this could have happened since B is of length 11, which means my vector A has 11 ranges which will be compared). In this example, only the second range would have fulfilled the condition. Therefore the output would be 1. It would also be great, if it were possible to say that it was the second range which fulfilled the condition. Hence the output would be like this:

```
count: 1     range: 2
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Whence is the threshold in your comparison?  Would it be in another vector, or somehow contained in the data you already gave above?

Comment: I did edit my post to give more info what I want.

Comment: Yes, the thresholds are fixed.

Comment: I have posted my result based on the example. It is 1. Because both thresholds are only once fulfilled in this example.

Comment: @akrun: yes, exactly. They are both below 20 but neither of them is above 23. Therefore, it is 0.

Comment: In the second range, we compare `20 19 24 24 `. In this range, we have a value (19) which is below 20 and two values which are above 23 (two times 24). Therefore this range fulfills the condition and we count 1.

Comment: @akrun What I wrote above (at the end of my post) is the full output.

Comment: @akrun Ahh no, sorry. Both conditions have to be met to count 1. Everything else is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
res <- tapply(A,rep(seq_along(B), B), FUN=function(x)  any(x < 20) & 
                    any(x>23))+0L
res 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
# 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 

d1 <- data.frame(count=res, range=names(res))
head(d1,3)
#   count range
#1     0     1
#2     1     2
#3     0     3
```

#### data

```
A <- c(10, 10, 20, 19, 24, 24, 17, 18, 24, 24, 24, 25, 16, 16, 16, 
   25, 25, 12, 12, 12, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 2, 2)
B <-  c(2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2)
```

Comment: It seems to work for you, but in my case it, I didn't get the 1.

Comment: My second line of the output is only zeros: '0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 '

Comment: @FRV I posted the data that was used.  Copy/paste that data and check if the code works

Comment: I'm sorry! You are absolutely right! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @FRV No problem  Perhaps you had used a different dataset